# how to insert a big list into a sqlite table with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

i don't understand very well flask_sqlalchemy but as far as i get, if i have a pandas(130 columns, 1 row) dataframe and i want to insert it into a sqlite db i should first build a class "Mytable"  like

```
class Mytable(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'mytable'
      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
      val0 = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
      val1 = db.Column(db.String(64))
      .
      .
      .
      va129 = db.Column(db.String(64))
      def __repr__(self):
             return '<Mytable %r>' % self.name
```

for the table, w/ the columns matching between the pandas and the sqlite db table, then use something like

```
mytable = Mytable(col1=pandas[0],col1=pandas[1],......)
db.session.add(mytable)
db.session.commit()
```

in order to insert it on the database, is this true? is there any less painful way to create the 130 columns table class? do you have any advice in order to avoid writing all the 130 lines from Mytable class and the mytable line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved whit this method, if encode_pd is the row to insert on Mytable we can use

```
row_to_write = list(encode_pd.loc[0])
row_value_markers = ','.join(['?']*len(row_to_write))
engine.execute("INSERT INTO Encodes VALUES (%s)"%row_value_markers, row_to_write)
```